# Foreach versus list-each in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Is there any difference in the following methods?

```
$fruit = array(
    'a' => 'apple',
    'b' => 'banana',
    'c' => 'cranberry'
);

// List-each method
reset($fruit);
while (list($key, $val) = each($fruit)) {
    echo "$key => $val\n";
}

// foreach method
foreach ($fruit as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $val\n";
}
```

Comment: Second method (`foreach`) is faster.

Comment: Which one looks cleaner?

Comment: http://www.phpbench.com/ OR http://m.metamorphosite.com/php-benchmarks-loops-arrays#Foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` start iteration from `current` element whereas `foreach` start from the `first` element.

In case you've already iterated the `array`, `list` will start from the next element from the previous iteration. You need to `reset` the `array` if you want to iterate from the first element.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned, there isn't. Except for the foreach() function looking cleaner imo.

Answer (score 0):

`each()` remembers its position in the array, so if you don't `reset()` it you can miss items.

```
reset($array);
while(list($key, $value) = each($array))
```

For what it's worth this method of array traversal is ancient and has been superseded by the more idiomatic foreach. I wouldn't use it unless you specifically want to take advantage of its one-item-at-a-time nature.

> array **each** ( array &$array )
>
> Return the current key and value pair from an array and advance the
>   array cursor.
>
> After each() has executed, the array cursor will be left on the next
>   element of the array, or past the last element if it hits the end of
>   the array. You have to use reset() if you want to traverse the array
>   again using each.

Read this [link](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/5/3/0/the-two-ways-of-iterating-through-arrays) for more explanation.